# libGDX Sprite failing to render

Tags: java, libgdx

[The full code is on GitHub](https://github.com/Cave-Dweller/Pong).

I'm fairly certain the issue with rendering is in Pong.java (src/com/me/pong/Pong.java) in the `render()` method:

```
    @Override
    public void render() {
            update();

            Gdx.graphics.setTitle("Pong | " + (int)(1.0f/Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()) + " FPS" );

            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            camera.update();
            batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

            batch.begin();
            for(Entity e : entities) {
                    e.draw(batch);
            }
            batch.end();
    }
```

as there doesn't seem to be any issue with `sprite` in `Ball` or the texture loaded for use.

It could also potentially be due to the positioning of the `Ball` to start off with, but I'm doubtful of that because the points are correct (in `update()`, I print the x coordinate from `sprite` when it goes off one side or the other, and so far I haven't seen unexpected values).

I've tried finding more information on the official libGDX documentation, but can't find anything on, for example, the coordinate system for sprites vs raw coordinates (they seem to be different). I've also tried some fixes proposed on other StackOverflow threads [e.g. this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350101/understand-libgdx-coordinate-system-and-drawing-sprites), but nothing seems to change the output of the program, at least not ostensibly.

The main issue is simply not being able to render the `Ball` for some unknown reason that I'm trying to determine and fix. I have some ideas but I don't know where to go from here.

If other snippets need to be posted for better analysis, I'll be happy to post them.

Comment: What is your Entity? Is it a subclass of a libgdx class? What is the code for entity.draw(batch)? Where do you set the position of your camera?

Comment: What about the size? this code has nothing wrong

Comment: @Springrbua You can find Entity at src/com/me/pong/Entity.java. It's a plain interface that is supposed to include the most basic methods for any game entity. I'll add it to the main post, if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the code. You create the following cam:
`camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, h/w);`
If you look at the API the constructor of the cam takes Viewport hight and Viewport width. You set the `hight = 1` and the `with = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/Gdx.graphics.getHight();`
Then you set the `Ball`s position to `Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHight() / 2`. As you only look at the coordinates from `P1(0/0)` to `P2(1/0.x) (depends on screenresolution)` you can not see your object, it is out of range. Set your camera viewport to something like 80 width and 45 hight (16/9). Then you can place your objects in your own world coordinate system (40, 22.5 is in the middle).

Comment: Ah! That fixed it, thank you. Any idea on how to "shift" the camera over so that the bottom left of the window is (0.0, 0.0)? It's quite frustrating trying to figure out where everything belongs with this slightly unintuitive positioning.

Comment: You have to set the cams position to camWidth / 2 , camHeight / 2. Thats because the cameras 0,0 are in its middle.