# Fix messd up coordinates

Tags: java, android, libgdx, coordinates

Im currently programming a Game where you have to avoid Asteroids(picture). Unfortunately I messed up my coordinate Systems. Today i wanted to add some Buttons but when it comes to setting Coordinates its more like trying Coordinats than excactly knowing what to do.
I have set a WIDTH and HEIGHT for my Game and a OrthoCamera Class that is inheriting from OrthographicCamera and responible for making the Game look same on every Device.

MyGdxGame Class:

```
public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener {


SpriteBatch batch;
ShapeRenderer renderer;
OrthoCamera cam;
public static int WIDTH = 1080 , HEIGHT = 720; // "resolution"
```

OrthoCamera Class:

```
public class OrthoCamera extends OrthographicCamera {

Vector3 tmp = new Vector3();
Vector2 origin = new Vector2();
VirtualViewport virtualViewport;
Vector2 pos = new Vector2();

public OrthoCamera() {
    this(new VirtualViewport(MyGdxGame.WIDTH, MyGdxGame.HEIGHT));
}
```

I also have made the Game Screen "bigger" to create more Room for flying Asteroids.

Asteroids Class:

public class Asteroids extends Entity {

```
private final int anzahl = 150;
private float xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
private List<Asteroid> asteroids = new ArrayList<Asteroid>();

private final int zyklischeRandbedingungenVielfaches = 2;

public Asteroids() {

    xMin = MyGdxGame.WIDTH * (-zyklischeRandbedingungenVielfaches);
    xMax = MyGdxGame.WIDTH * (zyklischeRandbedingungenVielfaches);
    yMin = MyGdxGame.HEIGHT * (-zyklischeRandbedingungenVielfaches);
    yMax = MyGdxGame.HEIGHT * (zyklischeRandbedingungenVielfaches); 

    for (int i = 0; i < anzahl; i++) {
        Asteroid a = new Asteroid( xMax,  yMax, asteroids);
        asteroids.add(a);
    }

}
```

Asteroid Class:

```
 public void update(float deltaT, float xMin, float xMax, float yMin, float yMax) {
    p.x += v.x * deltaT;
    p.y += v.y * deltaT;

    while(p.x > xMax)
    {
        p.x -=  (xMax - xMin);  
    }
    while(p.x < xMin)
    {
        p.x += (xMax - xMin);
    }
    while(p.y > yMax)
    {
        p.y -= (yMax - yMin); 
    }
    while(p.y < yMin)
    {
        p.y += (yMax - yMin); 
    }
```

[image: Game]

For instance thats how i set the position of the Play Button:

```
   texture = new Texture("button.png");

    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(texture, 59, 52, 300,250);

    sprite = new Sprite(region);
    sprite.setSize(sprite.getWidth() / 2, sprite.getHeight() / 2);
    sprite.setOrigin(-sprite.getWidth() / 2, -sprite.getHeight() / 2);

    sprite.setPosition(MyGdxGame.WIDTH / 2  - 317, MyGdxGame.HEIGHT /2 - 110); //!!!
```

[image]

Hope someone can tell me how to create more simple coordinates. -Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of the docs [here](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html). Specifically:

> A Sprite is always rectangular and its position (x, y) are located in
>   the bottom left corner of that rectangle.

So if you have a coordinate you want to centre your sprite on, you need to ensure you subtract half the width and half the height of your sprite from that coordinate.

See the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350101/understand-libgdx-coordinate-system-and-drawing-sprites) if you need further details.